# Using a variable in the web browser control

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am developing a windows phone 7.1 application, which will search through different search engine after taking in the text from the textbox. I have textbox(**searchBox**), four buttons for bing, google, facebook and yahoo and a web browser control. Now i need to pass the text from the textbox to the web browser. But the thing is it should be of the form "www.bing.com?q= **textbox.text**". how can i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust `WebBrowser.Url` property

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url.aspx

Or you can use `Navigate` method

```
  var address = "www.bing.com?q=" + textbox.Text;
  webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(address));
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161352.aspx